# os.walk() results type

Tags: python, tuples, os.walk

I have a folder of several thousand files. I need to match the filename of each file with a column from another array.

```
import os

filenames = []
for files in os.walk("Directory"):
    filenames.append(files)
```

I now have a tuple of every filename in the directory. What I want now is to splice each element of the tuple, and add that to a new array. My code looks similar to this:

```
files = []
for i in filenames:
    files.append(i[2:7])
```

I get the error, "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'."
After searching around here, I tried other commands like join. I tried converting filenames to a list.

Even when I say something like:

```
filenames[0]
```

expecting to get only the first string result, it returns the entire filenames array. Is there any way around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well `os.walk` yields a 3-tuple.  Try looking here for why you get that error: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: I thought that by only asking for files from os.walk in my for loop, it would not be in a 3-tuple anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.walk` returns a 3 tuple: `root, dirs, files`

Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

You could use list comprehensions to achieve the split based on filenames.

```
filenames = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [files for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.')])
files = [name[2:7] for name in filenames]
```

Here are the explanations:
Lambda functions are anonymous functions. You do not return anything. The definition contains expressions which are returned. This is powerful in processing dynamically generated data.

`reduce()` a.k.a "worker function" accepts two arguments. The function is called with first two elements of the list, then with the result of these, the third element, and so on. The return value is a single list

There are loads of documentation around this online.

Comment: @CalderEthan See if the edit would suffice your needs. Is it acceptable to have one consolidated list?

Comment: That does exactly what I need it to do! Thank you so much. Would you mind explaining several things to me, as I have not encountered the lambda or the reduce method before.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will continue reading about them. You've been a great help!

Answer (score 1):

I actually needed to include the path in the filenames and found this useful using list expressions. Since this helped me, I wanted to add the solution that gives a list with the full path:

```
onlyfiles = reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [map(lambda x: root + "/" + x, files) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath)])
```